# Typedef closure definition in Scala

Tags: scala

Is there something similar to a typedef in Scala for closures?

Something similar to:

```
typedef (a: Any*) => Boolean MyType
```

Comment: `closures` are not defined by their type but by implementation. A function with some specific type can be a closure or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
type MyType = (Any*) => Boolean
```

N.B. the `type` keyword can't be used at the `package` level; use it in an `object`, `trait` or  `class` (or `package object`).

Comment: what does the star after Any indicate?

Comment: This is equivalent to varargs in Java.